# Change Toooltip Color Javascript

Tags: colors, tooltip

Looking to change the color of my tooltip but not having much success. Is this a simple need for a color onto the dojo.style command? Here is my code so far

```
// create node for the tooltip
      var tip = "Click on problem location";
      var tooltip = dojo.create("div", { "class": "tooltip", "innerHTML": tip }, map.container);
      dojo.style(tooltip, "position", "fixed");

      // update the tooltip as the mouse moves over the map
      dojo.connect(map, "onMouseMove", function(evt) {
        var px, py;        
        if (evt.clientX || evt.pageY) {
          px = evt.clientX;
          py = evt.clientY;
        } else {
          px = evt.clientX + dojo.body().scrollLeft - dojo.body().clientLeft;
          py = evt.clientY + dojo.body().scrollTop - dojo.body().clientTop;
        }

        // dojo.style(tooltip, "display", "none");
        tooltip.style.display = "none";
        dojo.style(tooltip, { left: (px + 15) + "px", top: (py) + "px" });
        // dojo.style(tooltip, "display", "");
        tooltip.style.display = "";
        // console.log("updated tooltip pos.");
      });

      // hide the tooltip the cursor isn't over the map
      dojo.connect(map, "onMouseOut", function(evt){
        tooltip.style.display = "none";
      });
```